# I can't figure out why a regexpre return pages that are not supposed to match

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Using a regexpr advanced filter to narrow down the list of pages matching my criteria, GA is including pages that in theory should not be part of the returned data set.

This is the regular expression

```
^/s/*
```

and I got pages like

```
/sp_registration/preinscription.html
/sp_registration/activity.html
```

on top of those starting for /s/. I tried to escape the / doing something like `^\/s\/*` without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/*` means "zero or more forward slashes". Try `/.*` - this means one forward slash followed by anything.

Comment: No problem. If this was helpful, feel free to mark this answer as accepted so the question can be closed.